# Is it possible to conclude a $L^1$ function 0 almost everywhere using it fourier transformation?

Tags: fourier-analysis, lebesgue-measure, harmonic-analysis

> For a Lebesgue integrable functionon $f$ defined on $\mathbb{T}=[0,2\pi]$
>
> $\forall k\in\mathbb{Z}\quad\int_\mathbb{T}f(x)e^{-ikx}\frac{dx}{2\pi}=0$
> Is this sufficient to conclude that $f(x)\equiv0 $ almost everywhere?

I just begin to learn this part. I have no idea about this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fejer kernel gives a possible solution.

Comment: This is a nice exercise with the multiplicative system theorem, if you know it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fourier series of $\chi_{[a,b]}$ converges to $\chi_{[a,b]}$ in such a way that
$$
      \int_{\mathbb{T}}\chi_{[a,b]}(x)f(x)=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \int_{\mathbb{T}}\left(\sum_{n=-N}^{N}\int_{\mathbb{T}}\chi_{[a,b]}(t)e^{-int}dt e^{inx}\right)f(x)dx \\
  = \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{n=-N}^{N}\int_{\mathbb{T}}\chi_{[a,b]}(t)e^{-int}dt \int_{\mathbb{T}}f(x)e^{inx}dx
$$
And the right side is $0$ under the assumption that $\int_{\mathbb{T}}f(x)e^{inx}dx=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. So, for such an $f$,
$$
      \int_{T}\chi_{[a,b]}(x)f(x)dx = 0, \;\;\; \forall a,b.
$$
You can then use the Lebesgue differentiation theorem to conclude that $f=0$ a.e. by differentiating with respect to $a$ or with respect to $b$.

Comment: I think the first equation has changed the integration sign with the limitation one. Would you mind explaining it more clearly? It's interesting for me to see the Fubini's plays such a role here. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Oolongmilktea : You need some kind of convergence theorem for the Fourier series in order to make the interchange of operations. If you want, you can use a function that is $1$ on $[a,b]$, is $0$ outside $[a-\epsilon,b+\epsilon]$ and is linear in between. That function will have a uniformly convergent Fourier series, which makes the interchange easier. Then you can let $\epsilon \downarrow 0$ to obtain my last equation.